# Is it possible to get elapsed time in microseconds in Swi-Prolog?

Tags: time, prolog, swi-prolog

Simple question.

I need to calculate how long it takes to execute predicate X. So I wrote this predicate:

```
chronometrise(X) :-
    write('Executing: '), write(X), nl, nl,
    statistics(walltime, _), call(X), statistics(walltime, [_,E]),
    nl, write('Time: '), write(E), write(' ms.'), nl.
```

This allows me to get time in milliseconds. But I need microseconds.

Is it possible to calculate this in Swi-Prolog? Or milliseconds is best accuracy?

EDIT: Well, I found a better way: execute predicate 1000 times and calculate elapsed time. This will give us average execution time in milliseconds multiplyed by 1000, which is exactly average elapsed time in microseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `statistics(walltime, _)`, use `get_time(Time)`.  This returns a wall time stamp as a float.  The resolution of the reported time depends on the OS.  The `walltime` statistics originates from Quintus compatibility.